# Chemdraw: how to shorten the default length of the arrow of "Clean up Reaction"

Tags: chemdraw

In Chemdraw, there is a handy function of `Clean up Reaction` in the `Structure` menu, which automatically adjust the positions of each role of the selected reaction so that you don't have to align everything manually. For those who aren't familiar with it, here are screenshots for demonstration:

[Before applying `Clean up Reaction`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB6EZ.png)

[After applying `Clean up Reaction`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUSkk.png)

The only thing I'm not satisfied with is the default arrow length. As you can see in the After image, the arrow automatically adjusted by the software is too long, with unnecessary blank at each side of the arrow. When drawing a longer route of synthesis, this quickly makes the entire drawing too large to fit in a single page. Manually adjusting each arrow and structure is a chore. Does anyone know about how to modify the default length of the arrow after applying this function? Many thanks.